# Yii2 : Dynamic Form wbraganca

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dynamicform

I want to use dynamic form widget (wbraganca). I tried it using the tutorial by 'doingItEasy' channel & also by github. And wrote following code :

controller code -

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Vendors();
        $modelsSubCat = [new BusinessSubCategories];
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            $modelsSubCat = Model::createMultiple(BusinessSubCategories::classname());
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsSubCat, Yii::$app->request->post());

            // validate all models
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsSubCat) && $valid;
            $modelsSubCat = Model::createMultiple(BusinessSubCategories::classname());

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        foreach ($modelsSubCat as $modelSubCat) {
                            $model->ven_sub_category_id = $modelSubCat->bsc_id;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelSubCat->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ven_id]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsSubCat' => (empty($modelsSubCat)) ? [new BusinessSubCategories] : $modelsSubCat
            ]);
        }
    }
```

'_form.php' code -

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
?>
<div class="vendors-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_company_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_main_category_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_sub_category_id')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
             <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 4, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelsSubCat[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    // 'bsc_id',
                    'bsc_name',
                    'bsc_image',
                    'bsc_description',
                    'bmc_id',
                ],
            ]); ?>

            <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
            <?php foreach ($modelsSubCat as $i => $modelSubCat): ?>
                <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Sub Categories</h3>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (! $modelSubCat->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelSubCat, "[{$i}]id");
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?= $form->field($modelSubCat, "[{$i}]bsc_name")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelSubCat, "[{$i}]bsc_image")->fileInput(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelSubCat, "[{$i}]bsc_description")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- .row -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
            </div>
    </div>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_services_offered')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_business_logo')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_company_descr')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_established_date')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_noof_emp')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_branches_loc')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_market_area')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_website')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_specialized_in')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_contact_no')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_email_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_country_id')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_state_id')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_city_id')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_location_id')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_zip')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_contact_person_id')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_verified')->dropDownList([ 'Y' => 'Y', 'N' => 'N', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_created')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_updated')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ven_deleted')->dropDownList([ 'Y' => 'Y', 'N' => 'N', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("beforeInsert", function(e, item) {
    console.log("beforeInsert");
});

$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
    console.log("afterInsert");
});

$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("beforeDelete", function(e, item) {
    if (! confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
    console.log("Deleted item!");
});

$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("limitReached", function(e, item) {
    alert("Limit reached");
});
</script>
```

'create.php' code -

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Vendors */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Create Vendors');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Vendors'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="vendors-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelsSubCat' => $modelsSubCat
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

But What happens is that the add/remove button is not working. I'm showing it's screenshot - [Screenshot with Add/remove buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnxWw.png)

Comment: Do you got any errors in your console?

Comment: No. Just add/remove buttons are not working, no any action after clicking on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried, but i can't reproduce this issue here. Can you try fix the following lines and see if the problem was there?

1. You are not closing the `<div class="row">` after the dynamic form.
   This could mess up the html code.
2. In your `formFields`, you don't need to add the `'bmc_id'` if the
   model have one. Remove it. By the way, you are using:

   ```
   Html::activeHiddenInput($modelSubCat, "[{$i}]id");
   ```

   Make sure this is the correct name of the attribute.
3. Non-related with your issue, you have a second:

   ```
   $modelsSubCat = Model::createMultiple(BusinessSubCategories::classname());
   ```

   After the `loadMultiple` method, making it useless.

**EDIT**

Just occurred to me: by any chance you have more than one `DynamicForm` in the same view? Or the code is the same as you posted?

Answer (score 2):

1)first add

$form = ActiveForm::begin([

```
    'options' => [
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        'id' => 'dynamic-form'
    ]
]);
```

instead your

2) delete 'bmc_id' from attributes of dynamic form or add textinput to dynamic form with bmc_id column

3) check if exist your model Model (...Model::loadMultiple($modelsSubCat, Yii::$app->request->post());)